# There's a small red bump on my dog's stitches after neutering. From one of the stitch there was some oozing. It looks concerning

Tags: dogs, neutering, surgery

So I had my 1.5 year old labrador dog neutered and it's been one month since neutering everything was fine at first but today I noticed there were some small red bumps on the stitches and it was oozing too.

Comment: the first thing  to do is to contact your vet so she/he can take a look at it and the stitches should have been removed by your vet after a couple of weeks.